# How to load/reference a file as a File instance from the classpath

Tags: java, classpath

I have a file that is in my classpath, e.g. `com/path/to/file.txt`. I need to load or reference this file as a `java.io.File` object. The is because I need to access the file using `java.io.RandomAccessFile` (the file is large, and I need to seek to a certain byte offset). Is this possible? The constructors for `RandomAccessFile` require a `File` instance or String (path).

If there's another solution to seek to a certain byte offset and read the line, I'm open to that as well.

Comment: Working end to end example is here for details: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java/49120666#49120666]

Answer (score 232):

Try getting hold of a URL for your classpath resource:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/com/path/to/file.txt")
```

Then create a file using the constructor that accepts a URI:

```
File file = new File(url.toURI());
```

Answer (score 48):

This also works, and doesn't require a /path/to/file URI conversion.  If the file is on the classpath, this will find it.

```
File currFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("the_file.txt").getFile());
```

Comment: This worked for me whereas this did not: URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/com/path/to/file.txt").  Was this because the file I was loading was in a folder called "resource" rather than being in a package/folder shared by "this.getClass()"?  Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Really concise answer.

Comment: This wont work if the resource path (or a parent path of a relative resource) contains spaces. getFile() returns a URL encoded string with %20s that the File(String) constructor interprets literally. @joelittlejohn answer below will correctly handle this case as it passes a URI to the `File` constructor

Answer (score 21):

I find this one-line code as most efficient and useful:

```
File file = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("com/path/to/file.txt").getFile());
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: This worked for me and is the cleanest answer on this page.

Comment: This wont work if the resource path (or a parent path of a relative resource) contains spaces. getFile() returns a URL encoded string with %20s that the File(String) constructor interprets literally. @joelittlejohn answer below will correctly handle this case as it passes a URI to the File constructor. Should be `File file = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("com/path/to/file.txt").toURI());`

Answer (score 6):

Or use directly the `InputStream` of the resource using the absolute CLASSPATH path (starting with the `/` slash character):

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/path/to/file.txt");
```

Or relative CLASSPATH path (when the class you are writing is in the same Java package as the resource file itself, i.e. `com.path.to`):

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");
```

Comment: And how would this allow the original poster to use java.io.RandomAccessFile?

Comment: Your answer is more proper, I admit, and that is why I voted it up. One can skip to a certain offset in a file using the `java.io.InputStream.skip(long)` method and then read a line, for example, by using the `java.io.BufferedReader.readLine()` method. The question was also aimed at other solutions than just the `RandomAccessFile` one.