# Scala: File object for testing (Resource?)

Tags: file, scala, unit-testing

I need to pass a File to a class for unit tests.  The class requires a File specifically, and can't be modified - it just reads it.  (So I don't want to try to mock out that class or modify it - just pass it the File it needs.)

What's the recommended way to do this?

I put the file in `src/test/resources/...` and just passed that entire path in, and, since the test is run in the project root dir, this works.  But this seems quite wrong.

**UPDATE:** To emphasize - the class needs a **File** object, not an **InputStream** or anything else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java resource as file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676097/java-resource-as-file)

Comment: @Noah - that Java question talks about getting an InputStream, I need a File object specifically

Comment: what about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359876/how-to-load-reference-a-file-as-a-file-instance-from-the-classpath

Answer (score 0):

`this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName)` is recommended way to read files from resources

Comment: See update that I need a File object, not an InputStream

Answer (score 0):

If you need to look up something on the classpath and have it returned as a `File`, try this:

```
import java.net.URL
import java.io.File

object Test extends App {
  val fileUrl: URL = getClass.getResource("Test.class")
  val file : File = new File(fileUrl.toURI())
  println(s"File Path: ${file.getCanonicalPath}")
}
```

It more or less uses all Java classes, but it works. In my example, the `Test` object is finding its own compiled classfile, but you can obviously change it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM doesn't have a concept of getting a classpath resource as a `File` because resources don't necessarily correspond to files. (Often they're contained in jars.)

Your test could start by getting an `InputStream` and copying it into a temporary file.