# Finding a resource in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am developing a Java application which displays a big amount of images. The problem is I can't figure out how to make Java find these images.

I have followed several tutorials and answers here at Stackoverflow, but I still haven't managed to find a solution that works regardless of OS (Linux or Windows) and running method (embedded on eclipse or exported jar file). This might be due to the fact that I am still a newbie, though.

I have created a class, which I call myIcon and through this class I mean to access all of these images. In the following code, I want to pass the string "resources/icon/image.gif" to the function getIconPath. The output should be a ImageIcon of this image, since this file exists. Despite that, if I pass to this function the path to an image that doesn't exist, null should be returned. In this case, my application will display a default image (a red x).

```
public class MyIcon {
    // some other functions and properties

    private static final ImageIcon getIconPath(String path) {
        File f = new File(path);

        if (f.exists()) {
            return new ImageIcon(path, "");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The resources folder is a sibling to the src folder in my directory structure. That is, both resources and src are subfolders of the root directory.

When I run the code above, no image is ever found. The default image is thus always displayed and getIconPath returns null.

I am also aware of the getResource method of ClassLoader, but I still don't really understand how these things should be used.

Comment: I believe you need to pass in a path from your system root (ex. C:/), not one relative to your project root.

Answer (score 0):

While running in eclipse, you should print out `f.getAbsolutePath()`. It probably doesn't point to your file. More generally, you want to access the file as a resource. See:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this - making sure that when you build a jar, the images are part of it, and accessing a resource within the jar.

For the first part, I am guessing that whatever you're using to build a jar, it will put your images into the META-INF folder, which should work without too much issue (if its not there, or in with the Java class/source in the generated jar, that might cause the lookup to fail)

There is another [Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359876/how-to-load-reference-a-file-as-a-file-instance-from-the-classpath) for the second part. The key is to make sure the images you want to load are on the classpath.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If `resources` is in classpath, you can find for the image at classpath, using [`getResource(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) or [`getResourceAsStream(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).

However, in a simple Java Project, even adding `resources` to build path, like this:

[image: Java Build Path]

it will just put the folder content, in other words, just `icon/...`, to `bin` folder, something like this:

[image: Bin folder]

So, since `resources` isn't in classpath, just `icon`, to retrieve the images, you'll need to inform as path only `/icon/image.gif`, like this:

```
URL url = YourClass.class.getResource("/icon/image.gif");
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
```