# How to open a file from jar?

Tags: java, file, netbeans

I have a project where I open some XML files to read and edit information.
This works fine when running in the IDE (Netbeans) but fails when I am building the project and running the .jar file.
Is there a reason why this might not work?
The path of the project in Netbeans is

```
NetBeansProjects\project\src\data
```

but when I am running the jar file, this path is

```
NetBeansProjects\project\build\classes
```

However, when I create the files in this folder, they still cannot be opened.

Comment: The reason is probably that the code is incorrect and should be fixed. I don't have any crystal ball, so I can't find the bug in your code, unless you post it.

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359876/how-to-load-reference-a-file-as-a-file-instance-from-the-classpath

Comment: It should be a classpath issue, make sure to have all the dependencies that you need in the jar. If you are a newbie, I advise to start from [Classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) and then googling.

Answer (score 0):

The XML files need to be in the classpath when the jar file is executed.

You can give the classpath using -cp option when executing the jar file. Similar question was answered here as well - [Run a JAR file from the command line and specify classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-jar-from-command-line-and-specify-classpath)