# How to set relative path for a folder in Maven java web application?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, web

I am creating a Maven web application which stores many policy files in `policy` folder. My source folder layout looks like :
[image]
I tried to set the folder path as policyLocation as shown below:

```
try {
    // InputStream aa =
    // Accesscontrol.class.getClass().getResource(aa);
    String AbsolutePath = new File("/").getAbsolutePath();
    String policyLocation = (new File("."))
            .getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + "policy";
    System.setProperty(
            FileBasedPolicyFinderModule.POLICY_DIR_PROPERTY,
            policyLocation);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Can not locate policy repository");
}
```

But this is returning my Eclipse folder. Is there anyway I can get the policy folder that is not inside Resource folder (cause it can't be included inside Resource) in java web application?

Comment: That kind of resource should normally be located in `src/main/resources` according to Maven and Java standards. Why isn't yours?

Comment: so can you give me code sample for setting the policy folder inside resources folder as policyLocation variable @E-Riz

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but in a webapp you can't rely on the file system being present or accessible. Most web apps are deployed as WARs, not folders and files.

Comment: All resources should be placed under `src/main/resources`. Then you access it with `SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream` and you read from the stream.

Comment: @Tunaki are you sure this will hold for folder also cause I want only folder path not file path

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that your application has more than 1 way to run:

- from within IDE (Eclipse) where certain things are done automatically for you (like compilation on the fly)
- when you build your web application using **maven**, do you build it as **jar**, **war**, or perhaps **ear** ? Once built, how do you deploy and run it?

Firstly you have to ensure that your build process (maven) includes the policy files in the distributable (e.g. in the **war** file) in a known location which you can reference. Then you can modify the classpath within the **jar** or **war** and to ensure that your policy files are on the classpath.

With such setup all you have to do is to address it as a resource [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359876/how-to-load-reference-a-file-as-a-file-instance-from-the-classpath)