# Loading a file in the resources directory? I have the filename in a properties file

Tags: java, spring, classpath

I have the following line in my default.properties file :

```
json.countries = json/countries.json
```

I load the properties file in spring pretty easily, using the following :

```
@PropertySource(value="classpath:config/default.properties")
```

the json directory lives inside src/main/resources.

This makes the full path /src/main/resources/json/countries.json

I already know how to parse the JSON file etc, but no matter what the hell I seem to do, my application cannot see that file.

Anyone know how I can get this to work?

Comment: If the file is in classpath, you may refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359876/how-to-load-reference-a-file-as-a-file-instance-from-the-classpath

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I follow... What do you mean by "In classpath"? All I did was create a resources directory, then add a subdirectory named "json", and then added a file inside there named countries.json.

Do I need to mess around with something else?

Comment: Simply "in classpath" means `countries.json` is in your jar file. the link is about how to read file from jar file .

Comment: Whoa, so hang on - if I want to do this, I can't just have the file be in there, run mvn package, and have it be in there? I have to put it in the jar afterwards? Damn - that isn't going to work for me then, this company doesn't allow introduction of external files after packaging.

Comment: Files in resources folder are automatically included in the ouput jar file by default in Maven. You can check this by open the jar file.

Comment: Ah yes - I see it in there actually!! But then how come when I do...         File currFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("json/countries.json").getFile());

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(currFile));

I am getting file not found exceptions?

Comment: Turns out that getFile() is incorrect when working with classpath. You need an inputstream instead. Now my problem is that I have no idea how to translate an inputStream to JSON.

Comment: Use InputStreamReader