# Tomcat7 can't find my txt file

Tags: java, file, servlets, tomcat7

I have a java web application project that consists of a java servlet and then a classic java file. The servlet calls the methods implemented in the java file.

One of these methods involves reading from a file and putting the contents of that file into an array. However, after trying BufferedReader,InputStream and classloader.getResource(), I still can't seem to get it to be able to find the txt file.

In the Tomcat directory, the java files plus the txt file are located in /WEB-INF/classes. So I am not sure why it cant find the file..

Would anyone be able to tell me the best way of trying to read from that file?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** This is my most recent attempt at trying to read from it, which resulted in the FileNotFound exception.

```
ClassLoader cl = testClass.class.getClassLoader();
File file = new File(cl.getResource("text.txt").getFile());

Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
```

Comment: Please, include the code where you get the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java resource as file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676097/java-resource-as-file) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359876/how-to-load-reference-a-file-as-a-file-instance-from-the-classpath

Comment: @Arpit tried all of those solutions and they didnt help me. Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without leading /

`ClassLoader cl = testClass.class.getClassLoader();
File file = new File(cl.getResource("text.txt").getFile());`

text.txt should be in WEB-INF/classes/ppp/text.txt where ppp is package path of testClass.

With leading /

`ClassLoader cl = testClass.class.getClassLoader();
File file = new File(cl.getResource("/text.txt").getFile());`

text.txt is searched for on classpath (tomcat/lib, WEB-INF/lib, WEB-INF/classes, etc.).

Comment: Ooh thank you, I had actually tried the first part of your answer with text,txt in the correct location and it still had trouble finding the file. But I just realised I don't have a named package, its just (default package in eclipse). So I'm wondering could that be causing a problem? 

I'll try it also with the leading /. One question: When you say it is searched on the classpath. Does that mean it doesn't have a specific place to be, it could be in either of the directories you listed (i.e. tomcat/lib, WEB-INF/lib, WEB-INF/classes, etc.) ?

Comment: I'm not sure all of the directories of tomcat's classpath but I know that the ones I listed are. Try creating logging file.getCanonicalPath() to see the exact path that is used.

Comment: I tried your leading / solution with my text file in the WEB-INF/classes directory and it worked for me! Thank you very much for your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
File file = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/path/to/file.txt").getFile());
```

Comment: thanks! just tried that and now theres no filenotfound error but a nullpointerexception error instead. Do you by chance have any idea why?